# Angularjs, Typescript, Uglify and static $inject: Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, uglifyjs

Receiving this error when trying to use a custom service that also uses an angular service:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- LocService
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/mX7TCPAO3VycUp4Nw2Oy?p=preview

The code is generated by the Typescript compiler.
I have been using http://jscompress.com/ to simulate uglify.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: `LocService.inject = ['$http'];`

Fix:

`LocService.$inject = ['$http'];`

Comment: Oh dear :-)  The order didn't seem to affect the problem.  Many Thanks.